# Zerobrane Studio IDE is giving "Uncaught lua script exception"

Tags: lua, zerobrane

My Zerobrane Studio is giving an error and I can't get into it.
I've done everything. Can someone help me?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest removing/renaming user.lua config file, as it looks like you've assigned some function to the "styles" value in the config. See the [location of the file in the documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-configuration#system-wide-configuration) (as it's system-dependent).